# php7ts.dll cannot load into server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Today I have installed `php7`, but when I restart the apache, it couldn't start. again despite I edited the `httpd-xampp.conf` file to config `php7`.
anyway I went to `C:/xampp` and run the `apache_start.bat`, then I saw the following error

```
Apache 2 is starting ...

httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 456 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

after that I checked those file and saw they're exist.
what can I do now?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Show us line 456 of `C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and line 17 of `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`

Comment: line 456 of httpd.conf : Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf" and line 17 of httpd-xampp.conf : LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all the components installed in the same x64/x86 version :

- Apache (`httpd.exe -v` to find out which one is installed)
- PHP 7 (`php.exe -v` to find out which one is installed)
- Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (check the list of your installed softwares on Windows)

If one of the above component is not in the same version than the others, you could get the `module could not be found` error.